# Arg min $E(X-b)^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Question is that 
Find $\arg\min E(X-b)^2$
where $X$ is a continuous random variable.

I think the minimum of $E(X-b)^2$ is $0$. Because $(X-b)^2$ is nonnegative.

But how can i find $\arg\min_b E(X-b)^2$ ? And can I find it whether I don't know about the shape of function of $X$ or $E(X-b)^2$ ? 
And the value I have to find is $b$ ?is that right? 
Then when $b= E(X)$ it will be 0.

My question is that
How to find $\arg\min_b E(X-b)^2$

Comment: This is the famous least squares problem. The answer is $E[X]$. But when $b = E[X]$, the functional value is not $0$, but $\text{Var}(X)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Write $\mathbb{E}(X-b)^2=\mathbb{E}(X^2-2bX+b^2)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-2b\mathbb{E}(X)+b^2$, and treat it as a quadratic expression in $b$.

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{argmin}_bE(X−b)^2=\operatorname{argmin}_b {E(X^2)-2bE(X)+b^2}$

It is equivalent to a quadratic optimization problem: let $b=E(X)$, we have
\begin{align}
\min E(X−b)^2
&=E(X^2)-2E(X)E(X)+E(X)^2 \\
&=E(X^2)-E(X)^2\\
&=Var(X)
\end{align}